# GLMM Models in R

Tags: r, glmm

I want to see if there is a significant relationship between the mating (response variable) and several explanatory variables such as individual number (categorical), leg movement (continuous) and the reuse of individuals (categorical). My data looks like this:

```
Mating  ID  Replication Shaking
1       M1  R1          10
0       M1  R2          14
0       M2  R1          15
0       M2  R2          12
1       M3  R1          14
0       M3  R2          17
1       M4  R1          19
0       M4  R2          22
1       M5  R1          18
0       M5  R2          16
1       M6  R1          17
```

1 means mating happened, 0 means did not occur.

I am trying to organize the data to apply a GLMM to the data, but have not  been able to do it. I followed the model proposed by Crawley for binary response with pseudorreplication but it does not work. The script goes like this:

```
model2 <- lmer(Mating~Replication+(1|ID), family=binomial, method="PQL")
```

Can somebody tell me what part is wrong and how could I fix it? If you know a better method, that will be really welcomed as well.

Comment: Can you describe the way in which it is not working? Is this only an R programming question?

Comment: Error messages exist for a reason... what does the error message say?